# Why does (host) GCC need to be built against the target's standard library?

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, gnu, toolchain

I've been looking into building cross-toolchains and have a general question about the compilation and workings of gcc.

The question is about this excerpt from the [official gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html):

> In order to build GCC, the C standard library and headers must be present for all target variants for which target libraries will be built (and not only the variant of the host C++ compiler).

Why is the target's standard library required to build the (cross) compiler itself? Shouldn't the (cross) compiler running on the host only require the host's standard library to be built and then be able to compile the target's standard library?

I also found this on crosstool-NG's [how a toolchain is constructed](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/toolchain-construction/):

> the final compiler needs the C library, to know how to use it, but: building the C library requires a compiler

This is consistent with what's stated above but I don't get why the final compiler needs to be built against a prebuilt target C library just *to know how to use it* later on. What is there to know for the host compiler about the target C library? Isn't it the linker's job to link target programs against the target's standard library at compile time?

Comment: The honest answer would be: Lazyness. The GCC cross toolchain bootstrap is full of ugly kludges and in places outright broken. As per your question: There actually was once a GCC cross bootstrap bug, where the automake/configure stage for the libc would fail, because configure did use the cross-compiler to build a feature test program and attempt to run it on the host architecture (which obviously doesn't work, unless one uses a combination of binfmtmisc and qemu to transparently support foreign architecture binaries).

Comment: The only thing I was able to find and know of is [`gnu/stubs.h`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/595c22ecd8e87a27fd19270ed30fdbae9ad25426/include/stubs-prologue.h#L1), that basically has `__stub_FUNCTION` which is used for [detecting if function exists](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libcpp/configure#L2139) when configuring gcc.

Answer (score -1):

Because that's the only way to ensure a working compiler for the target platform is created.  There's no point in creating a non-working compiler, distributing it to the target platform, and finding out *then* that it's useless.

In general, a non-shared-object executable file is only successfully created if there are no unresolved symbols.

Per the [GCC 11.2 "Overall Options" documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

> Compilation can involve up to four stages: preprocessing, compilation proper, assembly and linking, always in that order. GCC is capable of preprocessing and compiling several files either into several assembler input files, or into one assembler input file; then each assembler input file produces an object file, and linking combines all the object files (those newly compiled, and those specified as input) into an executable file.

So the final step is linking.  The [GNU linker 'ld' man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) states:

> Normally the linker will generate an error message for each
> reported unresolved symbol but the option
> `--warn-unresolved-symbols` can change this to a warning.

and

> **--error-unresolved-symbols**
> This restores the linker's default behaviour of generating
> errors when it is reporting unresolved symbols.

So, by default linking fails when there are unresolved symbols.

Why?

Because if there are unresolved symbols, the resulting executable file won't work when it's run.

And the only way to ensure there are no unresolved symbols is to have all the necessary libraries from the target platform available when cross-compiling so all symbols can be resolved when the new compiler executables are being linked.

Comment: OP didn't ask about the process of cross-compiling itself, but about the task of building a compiler (which is going to run on the host platfor) that will be used for the cross-compilation itself. And since the cross-compiler will be run on host architecture (and not the target) it obviously will be linked against the libraries of the host architecture, not the target architecture.

Comment: @datenwolf He's talking about the newly compiled cross compiler (that'll generate binaries for other  target architectures). The new cross-compiler needs libc of the target architecture to resolve the symbols correctly whenever it generates a binary for the target architecture.

Comment: @Fractal But isn't symbol resolution the linker's job?

Comment: @Flo I don't know the correct answer, but I'm guessing that `libc` might be the only way to know the target platforms ABI. In other words, `libc` defines the ABI of the platform?

Comment: @Fractal Yes, libc defines the ABI of the platform. But as I understand it, libc is just a set of functions that interface with a given platform, some of which are exposed by it's header file. And as long as the linker knows where to find these functions, it shouldn't be a problem for a binary to call them at runtime. Even if the compiler that built the binary wasn't built against said libc.

Comment: @Fractal: Yes, the new cross compiler (well, technically the linker) will later on need the target architecture libraries to do its job. But OP is asking about a stage where this doesn't matter yet, namely, creation of the compiler and the linker itself. *And it should be noted, that in order to build the target architecture libc in the first place, you got to have the (boostraping) compiler and linker beforehand!* Unfortunately the GCC build process is so byzantine, and the glibc full to the brim with arch specific stuff, that those problems OP experiences keep creeping in.

Comment: @Fractal: If you want to look a nice counterexample how thing can be done as well, look at LLVM. With LLVM there's no such thing as a dedicated cross compiler toolchain. You got LLVM and the one thing can target everything it supports without the need of a dedicatedly built variant for each target.